# Sliding-mode control is a model-based technique?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, modeling

The sliding mode control can be considered a *model-based* control? In my opinion yes since takes the information of the mathematical model of the system to be controlled handling with possible uncertainties of the model. Am I right?

Comment: Sounds like yes, because you actually need to model the system at some point. As opposed to PID where you don't need to know the system model at all. You can just fiddle with the parameters until it works.